# Custom Google Makers with DataLayer/GeoJson

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, markers

I'm currently having an Issue getting google markers to display custom images depending on the type. I have had it working in the past that only had one image for all the markers.

map.php

```
var map,
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-25)});

function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {lat: 53.927895, lng: -1.386487}
    });

    map.data.loadGeoJson('http://customers.auroracomputers.co.uk/customers-json.php');

    map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {   
        infoWindow.setContent(
            'Surname: ' + event.feature.getProperty('surname') + '<br>' +
            'Postcode: ' + event.feature.getProperty('postcode')
        );
        var anchor = new google.maps.MVCObject();
        anchor.set("position",event.latLng);
        infoWindow.open(map,anchor);


    });

    var iconBase = 'http://customers.auroracomputers.co.uk/icons/'
    var icons = {
      business: {
        icon: iconBase + 'business.png'
      },
      home: {
        icon: iconBase + 'home.png'
      },
      competitor: {
        icon: iconBase + 'devil.png'
      }
    };

    function addMarker(feature) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    map: map
    });
    }




    map.data.setStyle({
    icon: 'http://customers.auroracomputers.co.uk/icons/home.png',
    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    icon: icon.competitor.icon
    });






}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Customer-Json.php

```
for ($i=0;$i<$nrows;$i++){

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

?>
 <script> 
  {
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": [<?echo $row['lng'];?>,<?echo $row['lat'];?>]
  },
  "properties": {
    "surname": "<?echo $row['surname'];?>",
    "postcode": "<?echo $row['postcode'];?>",
    "type": "<?echo $row['type'];?>"
  }
  }<?php if( $i != $nrows-1 ){ ?>,<?php } ?>
  </script>
```

Comment: There are errors in the json data ~ you have multiple instances of `script` tags thoughout

Answer (score 0):

GeoJson markers are styled differently than native Google Maps Javascript API v3 markers.  See [Style GeoJSON Data in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#style_geojson_data), in particular the section on [Change Appearance Dynamically](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#change_appearance_dynamically).

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  var type = feature.getProperty('type')
  return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ ({
    icon: icons[type].icon,
    title: type
  });
});
```

[from the reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.StyleOptions):

> icon Type:  string|Icon|Symbol
>
> Icon for the foreground. If a string is provided, it is treated as though it were an Icon with the string as url. Only applies to point geometries.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/65sx7hyr/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map,
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -25)
  });

function initialize() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: 40.7127837,
      lng: -74.0059413
    }
  });

  // map.data.loadGeoJson('http://customers.auroracomputers.co.uk/customers-json.php');
  map.data.addGeoJson(testGeoJson)

  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    infoWindow.setContent(
      'Surname: ' + event.feature.getProperty('surname') + '<br>' +
      'Postcode: ' + event.feature.getProperty('postcode')
    );
    var anchor = new google.maps.MVCObject();
    anchor.set("position", event.latLng);
    infoWindow.open(map, anchor);
  });

  var iconBase = 'http://customers.auroracomputers.co.uk/icons/'
  var icons = {
    business: {
      icon: iconBase + 'business.png'
    },
    home: {
      icon: iconBase + 'home.png'
    },
    competitor: {
      icon: iconBase + 'devil.png'
    }
  };

  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var type = feature.getProperty('type')
    return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ ({
      icon: icons[type].icon,
      title: type
    });
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
// New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.00594130000002)
// Newark, NJ, USA (40.735657, -74.1723667)
var testGeoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-74.0059413, 40.7127837]
    },
    "properties": {
      "surname": "York",
      "postcode": " 10007",
      "type": "home"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-74.1723667, 40.735657]
    },
    "properties": {
      "surname": "Newark",
      "postcode": "07102",
      "type": "business"
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I note is the source json is corrupted, hopefully the following might help get that sorted.

```
<?php
    /*
        Customer-Json.php
        -----------------
        The original code had thousands of `<script>` & `</script>` tags
        which meant it was not valid json.

        I have assumed that the previous loop can be replaced with the
        more usual recordset iteration loop as shown below.

        Each row has items added to the json array which gets echoed at the
        end - there is not need for the script tags at all - just include the
        correct headers.
    */

    /* store data to be sent */
    $json=array();

    /* using object notation for ease */
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_object( $result ) ){

        $surname=$row->surname;
        $postcode=$row->postcode;   
        $lat=$row->lat;
        $lng=$row->lng;
        $type=$row->type;



        $json[]=array(
            'type'      =>  'Feature',
            'geometry'  =>  array(
                'type'          =>  'Point',
                'coordinates'   =>  array( $lng, $lat )
            ),
            'properties'    =>  array(
                'surname'   =>  $surname,
                'postcode'  =>  $postcode,
                'type'      =>  $type
            )
        );
    }

    $json=json_encode( $json );
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
    echo $json;
?>
```